# ¿Por qué no funciona TextField.setBackground (Color.red) en Java?

Tags: java

me ha surgido el siguiente problema, tengo que cambiar el color de fondo de un Textfield y para ello implemento el método .setBackground(Color.red). La función donde esta implementado se ejecuta correctamente. He comprobado que la linea entra con un System.out.println, he revisado los imports y todo parece correcto. De hecho esto ha estado funcionando hasta hace poco. He hecho una prueba con un TextArea en el mismo proyecto y si me funciona, pero en los TextFields no.
¿Podéis orientarme sobre cual puede ser el motivo por el que no cambie de color?.
Os paso detalle del codigo donde lo utilizo:

```
 public static boolean enter_ID() {
    int position;
    boolean check = false;

    if (F_Create_Admin.TF_ID_Card.getText().isEmpty()) {
        F_Create_Admin.L_Confirm_ID_Card.setIcon(Singleton.noncomplying);
        F_Create_Admin.TF_ID_Card.setBackground(Color.red);
        F_Create_Admin.TF_ID_Card.requestFocus();
        check = false;
        F_Create_Admin.L_Info.setText(SLanguages.lang.getProperty("TF_no_empty"));
        F_Create_Admin.L_Info.setBackground(Color.red);

    } else if (Validate.v_ID_Card(F_Create_Admin.TF_ID_Card.getText()) == false) {
        F_Create_Admin.L_Confirm_ID_Card.setIcon(Singleton.noncomplying);
        F_Create_Admin.TF_ID_Card.setBackground(Color.red);
        F_Create_Admin.TF_ID_Card.requestFocus();
        check = false;
        F_Create_Admin.L_Info.setText(SLanguages.lang.getProperty("id_incorrect"));
    } else {

        Admin admin = new Admin(F_Create_Admin.TF_ID_Card.getText());
        position = BLL_Admins.search_admins(admin);
        if (position >= 0) {
            F_Create_Admin.L_Confirm_ID_Card.setIcon(Singleton.noncomplying);
            F_Create_Admin.TF_ID_Card.setBackground(Color.red);
            F_Create_Admin.TF_ID_Card.requestFocus();
            check = false;
            F_Create_Admin.L_Info.setText(SLanguages.lang.getProperty("Id_exist"));
        } else {
            F_Create_Admin.L_Confirm_ID_Card.setIcon(Singleton.complying);
            F_Create_Admin.TF_ID_Card.setBackground(Color.green);
            F_Create_Admin.TF_Name.requestFocus();
            if (F_Create_Admin.TF_Name.getText().equals("NAME")) {
                F_Create_Admin.TF_Name.setText("");
            }
            F_Create_Admin.L_Info.setText("");
            check = true;
        }

    }
    return check;
}//End of enter ID Function
```

Comment: Que es F_Create_Admin? Es muy raro que no funcione, podrías revisar si en algún otro lugar se esta sobre escribiendo el color.

Comment: @Elenasys. F_Create_Admin es el nombre del formulario donde se encuentran los TextFields que cambian de color. Cuando se abre el formulario aparecen en blanco, cuando se introduce un dato se comprueba que sea valido. Si es valido,el campo se pinta en verde y si no es valido se pinta en rojo

Comment: @Elenasys:Externamente no hay otra intervención sobre los campos de texto. Debería funcionar. De hecho ha estado funcionando pero no sé en que momento ha dejado de hacerlo. He estado trabajando en el jTable que contiene los datos de usuario pero la única relación que tiene con el formulario es la apertura del mismo mediante un botón o un doble click. No existe ningún evento que devuelva el campo al color blanco, ya que si el dato es valido se queda en verde y cuando se valida el formulario este se cierra. Se te ocurre algún otro motivo por el que pueda no funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

expongo aquí la solución al problema por si en un futuro le puede servir a alguien. El problema venia dado por la invocación a un look & feel que se realizaba en el constructor del JTable desde el que se abren los formularios. Me explico, tengo un JTable desde el cual, con unos botones, abro los formularios en los que tengo que pintar el fondo del textfield. Pues bien, es en el constructor de ese JTable donde se invoca al look & feel. Tan solo he tenido que eliminarlo y los textfields han vuelto a responder al método setBackgound().[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El look & feel solo debería ser establecido cuando arranca el sistema. Puede que la solución correcta sea eliminar la invocación del look & feel del componente `JTable`

Comment: Recuerdo esta pregunta de hace mucho tiempo, buena aportación. Saludos!